# Open Activity from Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I am new in android development and I got this error in runtime. I know that there was a lot of post with such error here but no one could give me answer. This already taken so much time of mine. Please help me!

I am tring to open Activity from Fragment. Unfortunatly program crash with such error. What I need to fix in my case? From Logcat I understand that problem with xml file and how I initialize it in java.

```
at www.smartavenue.com.WeatherActivity.onCreate(WeatherActivity.java:82)
```

in code its this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
```

Logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{www.smartavenue.com/www.smartavenue.com.WeatherActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at www.smartavenue.com.WeatherActivity.onCreate(WeatherActivity.java:82)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at www.smartavenue.com.WeatherActivity.onCreate(WeatherActivity.java:82)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_blue_with_linear_gradient.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020036
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at www.smartavenue.com.WeatherActivity.onCreate(WeatherActivity.java:82)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "@2131492868"
            at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
            at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:310)
            at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFloat(TypedArray.java:288)
            at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:898)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at www.smartavenue.com.WeatherActivity.onCreate(WeatherActivity.java:82)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_weather.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              style="@style/ActivityBackground"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/general_toolbar"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/city_list_container"
        style="@style/BlueBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.haringeymobile.ukweather.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

WeatherActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.general_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        isDualPane = findViewById(R.id.weather_info_container) != null;

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        workerFragment = (WorkerFragmentToRetrieveJsonString) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(WORKER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (workerFragment == null) {
            workerFragment = new WorkerFragmentToRetrieveJsonString();
            fragmentTransaction.add(workerFragment, WORKER_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
        Fragment cityListFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (cityListFragment == null) {
            cityListFragment = new CityListFragmentWithWeatherButtons();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.city_list_container, cityListFragment,LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

**EDIT:**
style:

```
<style name="BlueBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_blue_with_linear_gradient</item>
</style>
```

background_blue_with_linear_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="@integer/background_shape_gradient_angle"
        android:centerColor="@color/yellow"
        android:endColor="@color/dark_blue2"
        android:startColor="@color/dark_blue2"
        android:type="linear" />

    <padding
        android:left="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:right="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/shape_corners_radius" />

</shape>
```

Comment: try removing `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);` line

Comment: Try to put `setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);` under the super

Comment: Post your @style/BlueBackground and the drawable that is associated with it.

Comment: `Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)` May be a problem with your class..

Comment: Where r u using background_blue_with_linear_gradient.xml?

Comment: Problem is with 

    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/background_blue_with_linear_gradient.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020036
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)

To track issue open your R.java and look for `resource ID #0x7f020036` , element associated with this ID is causing the problem.

Comment: Could you post code of `@style/BlueBackground` ?

Comment: I removed setTheme to different place and it didnt help me! I added to my post style part and  background_blue_with_linear_gradient.xml that I used. Can you check it guys?!

Comment: @theJango I opened my R.java document and checked it but I havent 0x7f020036. What I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

@NurzhanNogerbek : My bad sorry buddy, real exception in your code is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "@2131492868"
```

are you assigning some float value that has some character and could not be converted to float value. My wild guess is your line

```
<corners android:radius="@dimen/shape_corners_radius" />
```

providing radius as some invalid float. Please check all these values like radius, padding values.